# Qt Creator Editor I don't get "ui->" continue

Tags: qt, editor

In my Qt Creator project, when i do add some object like (line edits, buttons or etc...), i don't get them when i write ui->. I don't know what is the reason, cause everything was working very good to now. This happened immediately. Now in some of my other projects, everything is working, but in my main project nothing new can be declared. Is it possible something be wrong with my code? Or this is some problem from the Qt Creator editor.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Post some code, please

Comment: Well, my code is about 500 lines per class, so i can't post it, but i will describe it. It only contains, proxy filters, sql tables, and buttons. Thats it

Comment: If there is some way to reset my editor? Thanks

Comment: Try _run qmake_ and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Yes, they are all on place. And if i haven't mentioned, when i write ui-> , my old objects are coming and i can see them, but i can't see the objects that i've been declaring for the last two days.

Comment: Zlatomir, i've clicked on Build, and then on Run qmake, but it is not helping

Answer (score 0):

try 'make clean', qmake. Check if your ui gets set up correctly

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ...
}
```

Make sure ui-> is a known reference to the executing part.
Check for missing brackets.

Comment: I've checked everything Sebastian. Its ok, its weird, because i get only my old objects, from before week.

Comment: This definitly sounds as your moc files are not being generated again. You can try open up a shell / console for QT (should be available within your Qt-installation), switch to your working directory containing the .pro file and manually run "make clean" (or nmake clean on msvc) and manually running qmake. After this check the modification/creation date of your moc and ui files. These should have been changed to the current execution time. If not the problem relies in qmake not generating updating your files.